# Genexus problema con procedimientos REST en Docker

Tags: rest, docker, genexus, tomcat

Tenemos varios procedimientos en GX17 publicados como api REST, y están funcionando correctamente en un servidor con un tomcat9;  pero luego al hacer un deploy para Docker con la intención de migrar ya no funcionan y arroja un error 404.

Las pruebas de la app Docker  se hacen con Postman y el resultado para todos los api rest es siempre el mismo ...

**{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found"}}**

En los logs de la aplicación Docker muestra lo siguiente:

```
2022-10-20T15:23:31,968 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR com.genexus.WrapperUtils - Error executing REST service
jakarta.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:252) [jersey-server-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265) [jersey-common-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234) [jersey-server-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680) [jersey-server-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205) [jersey-container-servlet-core-3.0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:15) [gxwrapperjakarta.jar:?]
        at com.genexus.filters.InternalRestServicesFilter.doFilter(InternalRestServicesFilter.java:26) [gxclassR.jar:?]
        at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14) [gxwrapperjakarta.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at com.genexus.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:31) [gxwrapperjakarta.jar:?]
        at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1231) [gxclassR.jar:?]
        at com.genexus.servlet.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:14) [gxwrapperjakarta.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353) [catalina.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.0.5]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:10.0.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:10.0.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
```

Alguien tuvo el mismo problema y/o me podría dar una mano con esto?

**Desde ya muchas gracias !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como solución puse como main program En Valor True y lo añadí como parte de docker

Comment: Perfecto !   Me falto poner el valor main program en True. Muchas gracias !!